# How to add padding/Marging to ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using [SJSegmentedViewController](https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController) and loading two view controllers in SegmentController, I want to add padding 20 px to both of these controllers but I have tried but not able to achieve it,

If anyone knows how to Customise SJSegmentedViewController, please refer attached screenshot here.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let headerViewController = storyboard
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HeaderViewController1")

        let firstViewController = storyboard
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewController")
        firstViewController.title = "First"

        let secondViewController = storyboard
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        secondViewController.title = "Second"

        let segmentController = SJSegmentedViewController()
        segmentController.headerViewController = headerViewController
        segmentController.segmentControllers = [firstViewController,
                                                secondViewController]
        segmentController.headerViewHeight = 300.0

        navigationController?.pushViewController(segmentController, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the implementation of [`SJContentView`](https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController/blob/master/SJSegmentedScrollView/Classes/SJContentView.swift), I found that that library is not using a collection view to implement the paginated scroll which contains all view controllers. It's directly using a scroll view. The two function which handles the layout of the view controllers

1. `func addContentView(_ view: UIView, frame: CGRect)`
2. `func updateContentControllersFrame(_ frame: CGRect)`

do not provide support to add padding in between two views of two adjacent view controllers.

There are two ways, if you want to continue with `SJSegmentedViewController`

1. Add padding on your view controller's view rather wishing to have them in between views in the scroll view. Here the usable width of the screen will be reduced.
2. Create [an issue](https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController/issues/new) and ask for help.

Comment: how to deal with 1st options, any idea about it

Answer (score 0):

@user1374 Can you please try the following approach?

[image]

Comment: i my SJSegmentedViewController both view controllers created and designed programmatically

Comment: @user1374 I guess the strategy should be same, you can embed all the subviews into one `UIView` and after adding `layout constraints` for padding you can achieve the same. Please refer to the screenshot.